# Apple Touch Bar keys not firing keypress event

Tags: javascript, macbookpro-touch-bar

Is there another event I can listen for when I want to listen for an Apple Touch Bar keypress? Specifically, I would like to listen for the Escape keypress event.

My code is working on "regular" keyboards, with actual escape keys, but not with the Touch Bar.

```
listenForKeypressEvent = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.key === "Escape") {
        // do the things
    }
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', listenForKeypressEvent);
```

Comment: In which browser?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox. Keydown worked

Answer (score 8):

Using keydown instead of keypress works.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', listenForKeypressEvent);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it ideally be on 'keyup'?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but in my case `keyup` worked fine for me

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', listenForKeypressEvent);
```