# How do we detect the "keyDown/keyPress" events for Macbook Pro touch bar keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onkeydown, onkeypress, macbookpro-touch-bar

I recently came across a requirement to close a Modal on Esc key press (508 compliance). I then realised that the onKeyDown handler I wrote on my react component wasn't working as expected. The event wasn't getting fired on clicking Escape key from my macbook pro's touch bar. Has anyone gone through similar issue ?
If yes, is there a workaround ?

Comment: could you share the code for more clarification?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345866/apple-touch-bar-keys-not-firing-keypress-event You can use keydown or keyup instead of keypress

Answer (score 0):

You should write `onKeyDown={(e) => yourFunctionName(e)}` on the Modal element and your function should look like something like this

```
const yourFunctionName = (e) => { if (e.key === "ENTER") { closeModal() } }
```